# eq() how to select only specific element jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I thought eq() selected just the element required by the number passed in. In this example I just was the value of the second `<td>` element, but it is giving me both.

http://jsfiddle.net/r4fnt6pd/1/

I couldn't find a similar problem elsewhere, and looking over the jquery docs is just leaving me more confused as to why it's not working. The elements are generated by loops through data so they have no individual classes to directly reference the elements.

Thank you.

Comment: Your jsFiddle example doesn't actually run (no jQuery included, plus invalid markup - `tr` without a `table`, and `val()` where you mean `text()`). Fixing those conditions, it works fine - the table is shown, then the single value you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/r4fnt6pd/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not giving you both. The code doesn't get as far as getting anyting from any element, and if it would it wouldn't find any table cell.

Problems with the code and the fiddle:

- The HTML code is invalid. There is no `table` element, so the `tr` and `td` elements will be ignored and the content of them just ends up as text in the page.
- The jQuery library is not included in the fiddle, so the code will crash when you try to use `$`.
- You are using the `val` method, but the cell has no value. You would use the `text` method to get the text in the cell.

Put a `table` tag in the code:

```
<table>
  <tr class="pound"> <td>pound</td> <td>0.79</td></tr>
</table>
```

Use the `text` method:

```
var conFrom = $('.pound td:eq(1)').text();
```

Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4fnt6pd/2/

Comment: appologies the original file had the `<table>` tag, I just forgot it in fiddle, but it worked regardless for me. The solution was text() in place of val() Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can do any of the following. I also changed your 'val()' to a 'text()', as td elements don't have a val:

```
conFrom = $('.pound td:eq(0)').text()
```

or

```
conFrom = $('.pound td')[0].innerHTML
```

or

```
conFrom = $('.pound td').eq(0).text()
```

See [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4fnt6pd/4/)